# ASP.Net MVC migration: access field you're deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

During a code-first migration, is there any way to access a field that is guaranteed to still exist in the database but may not exist in your model anymore?

Context: I am trying to switch from a one-to-many-relation (a one-way reference) to a many-to-many-relation (a mapping table). Of course I would like to retain my data by inserting one entry for each pre-existing reference. And the migration seems the right place to do it. If I had a guarantee that the migration is always run *before* the source field is removed from the model (presumably by checking out a version control commit), I could e.g. include the following in my migration (assuming the referencing model is named `Foo` and the referenced one is named `Bar`):

```
Models.MyApplicationContext db = new Models.MyApplicationContext();
foreach(Models.Foo foo in db.Foos)
{
    foo.Bars.Add(foo.Bar);
}
```

But unfortunately, on other developers' computers as well as in the production environment, the `foo.Bar` field will be gone from the model by the time this migration is run, so I will need a different way to access this field (which is still in the database). Do I have any options besides writing plain SQL?

Edit 1: Minimal Working Example reduced model classes:

Before the migration:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    // or public int? BarId { get; set; }
    // (presumably only relevant for implementation details
    // unrelated to my question which I can figure out myself)
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

After the migration:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: share your model classes with us (before and after the change)

Comment: @user1859022 I have edited my question to include a MWE of my model classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alter the generated migration to execute an sql statement that fills your many to many table **before** the column gets deleted.

```
public partial class OneToMany : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Foos", "Bar_Id", "dbo.Bars");
        DropIndex("dbo.Foos", new[] { "Bar_Id" });
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.FooBars",
            c => new
                {
                    Foo_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Bar_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Foo_Id, t.Bar_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Foos", t => t.Foo_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Bars", t => t.Bar_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Foo_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Bar_Id);

        // HERE:
        this.Sql("insert into FooBars select Id, Bar_Id from Foos");

        DropColumn("dbo.Foos", "Bar_Id");
    }
    ...
 }
```

This has a few advantages that you get for free:

- the statement runs inside the transaction so if something goes wrong the DB stays intact
- you can fill your mapping table w/o loading the old entities - will perform good with a large `Foos` table

Comment: Looks like I indeed can't get around using plain SQL, in which case your solution looks as elegant as it's gonna get. I will wait until monday to see if anyone proves me wrong on this over the weekend, if not then I will accept your answer. Either way thanks a lot!

Comment: the whole migration is done using plain SQL (call `update-database -verbose` to see it). It gets generated when the migration is executed. I know this feels _wrong_ at first but applying a migration is a completely different concept than using EF at runtime.